# jqgrid textbox value not getting update

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Problem: unable to get updatable value of textbox in jqgrid.

It just retrieve old value.
example - default value of textbox field inside jqgrid is - "0"
now, if i update its value to "1" and inspect the field then its value does not get updated into HTML and not able to retrieve with jqgrid object through below syntax.

`var rowData = $('#gerList').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);`

Below is my jqgrid stuff:

```
             $('#gerList').jqGrid({
            ajaxGridOptions: {
                error: function () {
                    $('#gerList')[0].grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                    alert('An error has occurred.');
                }
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEnrolls", "Attendance")/' + 0,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            postData: { adID: rowID },
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { root: 'List', page: 'Page', total: 'TotalPages', records: 'TotalCount', repeatitems: false, id: 'syStudentID' },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['GrdID', 'name', 'Minutes', 'comment'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'syID', index: 'syID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 150 },
                {
                    name: 'Min', index: 'Min', width: 75, align: 'left', formatter: function (cellValue, option) {
                        return '<input type="text" style="width: 40px" name="txtMin" id="txt_' + option.rowId + '" value="' + cellValue + '" />';
                    }
                },
                { name: 'MSG', index: 'MSG', width: 150 }
            ],
            pager: $('#gerListPager'),
            sortname: 'syStudentID',
            rowNum: 40,
            rowList: [40, 80, 120],
            width: '525',
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                console.log("final");
                var $txt = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]');
                alert($txt);
                 $txt.attr('value', rowid);
                 return true; // allow row selection*/
                return true;
            },
            sortorder: 'desc'
        }).navGrid('#gerListPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Please suggest me what is wrong to use this textbox in jqgrid.

In grid UI, all fields are non editable except textbox field appear to allow edit always.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
jQuery("#gerList").saveRow("rowid", false, 'clientArray');
```

Comment: where should i write ths `saveRow` code in jqgrid ? clientArray should keep at it is or, do i have to replace with some other value ? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use this after final you create grid `jQuery ("# ​​gerList") saveRow ("rowid", false, 'clientArray');` else se this [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)